# Live Webkit window for Splash using docker for Mac

Tags: docker, splash-screen

Hello fellow developers!

I'm having issues trying to make the live Webkit window in my Mac work, I tried using the code that is posted in the official documents:

```
docker run -e DISPLAY=unix$DISPLAY 
-v /Users/emilianoisaza/Desktop/crawlers/splash/Luascripts:/notebooks
-v $XAUTHORITY:$XAUTHORITY 
-e XAUTHORITY=$XAUTHORITY 
-p 8888:8888 
-it scrapinghub/splash-jupyter --disable-xvfb
```

I know it is written for linux, but I failed miserably. I'm a real newby with docker and would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried and search a lot of ways，finally it's working.
The question is similar to

> Running GUI applications using Docker for Mac

Steps:

1.Install XQuartz using following link

https://www.xquartz.org/

2.Run XQuartz

3.Host Machine IP

```
ifconfig en0 | grep inet | awk '$1=="inet" {print $2}'

export DISPLAY=192.168.199.193:0.0
xhost +
```

4.Running a container

```
docker run -v `/bin/pwd`/notebooks:/notebooks -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY -p 8888:8888 -it scrapinghub/splash-jupyter --disable-xvfb
```

It's working.

- reference：https://sourabhbajaj.com/blog/2017/02/07/gui-applications-docker-mac/